# Minor annoyance about the design

Tags: discussion, design

Why are the votes, number of answers and views set from left to right on the left of the questions in the [main page](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but vertically, from top to bottom, in the [list of questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Apart from the inconsistency, which is rather unnecessary, the vertical layout is rather illegible...

Comment: I agree.  I vote in favor of having both as horizontal!

Answer (score 6):

I guess the simple reason is that in the [list of questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) there is enough vertical space for the vertical layout of the numbers, and this gives more *horizontal* space for the preview of the question. (I actually like the vertical layout better.) On the [main page](https://math.stackexchange.com/), a vertical layout would just eat too much vertical space.